# Is there any way to move MKCircle overlay with MKUserLocation without flicking or blinking?

Tags: swift, mkmapview, swift5

Currently, I am using this code to draw the circle.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    if let overlay = overlay as? MKCircle {
        let circleRenderer = MKCircleRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        circleRenderer.fillColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.19)
        circleRenderer.lineWidth = 1
        return circleRenderer
    }
    return MKOverlayRenderer(overlay: overlay)
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didUpdate userLocation: MKUserLocation) {
    let circle = MKCircle(center: userLocation.coordinate, radius: self.regionRadius)
    print("\(userLocation.coordinate)")

    if (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .denied || CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .notDetermined)  {
        mapView.removeOverlays(mapView.overlays)
    } else {
        mapView.removeOverlays(mapView.overlays)
        mapView.addOverlay(circle)
    }
}
```

Current output:

[image]

It is working fine but the circle is blinking and flickering. I need a smooth movement of the circle. I am aware that it's an iOS 13 issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options:

1. I’ve found that, in general, the flickering effect is diminished if you add the new overlay before removing the old one.
2. You might consider making the circle an custom annotation view rather than an overlay. That way, you can just adjust the `coordinate` without adding/removing.

By putting the circle in the annotation, itself, it’s seamless, both with user tracking on:

[image]

I turned off user tracking half way through, so you could see both patterns.

```
class CirclePointerAnnotationView: MKAnnotationView {
    let circleShapeLayer: CAShapeLayer = {
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.lightGray.withAlphaComponent(0.25).cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        return shapeLayer
    }()

    let pinShapeLayer: CAShapeLayer = {
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        return shapeLayer
    }()

    let imageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "woman")
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        return imageView
    }()

    var pinHeight: CGFloat = 100
    var pinRadius: CGFloat = 30
    var annotationViewSize = CGSize(width: 300, height: 300)

    override init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        layer.addSublayer(circleShapeLayer)
        layer.addSublayer(pinShapeLayer)
        addSubview(imageView)

        bounds.size = annotationViewSize
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        let radius = min(bounds.width, bounds.height) / 2
        let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
        circleShapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * .pi, clockwise: true).cgPath

        let angle = asin(pinRadius / (pinHeight - pinRadius))
        let pinCenter = CGPoint(x: center.x, y: center.y - (pinHeight - pinRadius))
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: center)
        path.addArc(withCenter: pinCenter, radius: pinRadius, startAngle: .pi - angle, endAngle: angle, clockwise: true)
        path.close()
        pinShapeLayer.path = path.cgPath

        let imageViewDimension = pinRadius * 2 - 15
        imageView.bounds.size = CGSize(width: imageViewDimension, height: imageViewDimension)
        imageView.center = pinCenter
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageViewDimension / 2
    }
}
```